# Listing all service instances in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, service

I have here what would appear to be a simple task; listing all the instances of a service object actively managed by a WCF `ServiceHost` at any particular time.

For example, my service contract interface is `IFooService` and the implementation is `FooService` (with a per-session behaviour). On the service side I simply instantiate the service host using `ServiceHost(typeof(FooService))` and open it. Sessions are created, destroyed, and operations called as normal by clients - and for the most part, the fact that this functionality is hidden is good.

However, my goal is to expose a method in the class that declares the `ServiceHost` that lists all currently active instances of `IFooService` (or similarly `FooService`). Having the class track its own instances is possible, but doesn't seem too elegant. Is there any in-built method for WCF to return a list of all service object instances managed by a `ServiceHost`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of how to get the instances themselves, but the count can be gotten from the [instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733922.aspx) [performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need more than just the count. My current workaround is to store a list of WeakReferences pointing to all instances of the class, seems to be working well enough, perhaps not ideal though.